# Watching part of a page using urlwatch

Tags: python

I'm using `urlwatch` ([homepage](https://thp.io/2008/urlwatch/) | [GitHub](https://github.com/thp/urlwatch)), and I'd like to watch only the `"hammerhead" for Nexus 5 (GSM/LTE)` section of the [Nexus factory images](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) page. I'm not sure how I can do this, however. The [example hooks.py file](https://github.com/thp/urlwatch/blob/master/share/urlwatch/examples/hooks.py.example), used for filtering results, is rather unclear to me; I'm not sure how to use it/how to apply it to that section of the page only.

How can I watch just the `"hammerhead" for Nexus 5 (GSM/LTE)` section of the [Nexus factory images](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to try feeding the html you get from the page into some sort of XPath parser, or my preference, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def filter(url, data):
    if url == "https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images":
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
        return soup.select("h2#hammerhead ~ table")[0]
```

The `soup.select` line looks for a h2 element with the `id` `hammerhead`, then returns a list of all the `table` elements following it.  The first of these is the one you want, hence the `[0]`.

Comment: Perfect! That's an awesome library that I didn't know about, thank you! Only thing is that the `soup.select()` has to be cast to `str()`, otherwise urlwatch is unhappy and throws a `NoneType` exception.